# TextAppeareance of TextViews in a two item list

Tags: android

I have a list of items that have a text and a secondary text.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actor_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What are the recommended styles for the textViews `movie_title` and `actor_name`.

**Text size** of these textViews should also **scale** to `phone, 7" tablets and 10" tables.`

Comment: see `res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml` in your SDK

Comment: @pskink I know them. but the text sizes don't scale up for tablets

Comment: yes, it scales, for example `TextAppearance.Large` defines  `textSize` as `22sp`, see *res/values/styles.xml*

Comment: @pskink Suppose I assign a style of TextAppearance.Large to a TextView. So the text size would be 22sp on phone, 7" & 10" tablets. But 22sp height is same on phone, 7" & 10" tablets. Now for a list item, 22sp will look good on 10" tablet but would look really large on a phone. This is the scaling I am asking for ...

Comment: ok so use `dp` instead of `sp` as `sp` is also scaled by the user's preferred text size

Comment: For text size we should not use dp

Comment: ok you dont want to use neither `sp` nor `dp`, so what do you want to use? `px`?

Comment: I want to use the "recommended way". Using dp for textsize is outright wrong. And using simple_list_item_2.xml doesn't offers the scaling I am talking about. 22sp is same size/height everywhere.

Comment: yes using `dp` is wrong: the recommended way is using standard text appearance like `textAppearanceSmall` /  `textAppearanceMedium` /  `textAppearanceLarge` etc which all apps use and those standard text appearances use `sp` under the hood